# Gnome3 add all chrome apps to group in apps list

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, dconf, gsettings

I add folders to the gnome3 app list using gsettings set commands, i'm now trying to add all google chrome apps to a single folder / group.

The following is the relevant extract from my setup script:

```
applist='['$(printf "'%s', " $(cd /home/rob/.local/share/applications; ls chrome*.desktop))']'
echo "$applist"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['Utilities', 'Sundry', 'Office', 'Software', 'Utilities2', 'Media', 'ChromeApps']"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/ChromeApps/ name 'Chrome Apps'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/ChromeApps/ apps "${applist}"
```

I get the following error when running the script and cannot work out what is wrong:

```
['chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Default.desktop', 'chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Default.desktop', 'chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Default.desktop', 'chrome-cnciopoikihiagdjbjpnocolokfelagl-Default.desktop', 'chrome-hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki-Default.desktop', 'chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Default.desktop', ]
expected value:
  ['chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Default.desktop', 'chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Default.desktop', 'chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Default.desktop', 'chrome-cnciopoikihiagdjbjpnocolokfelagl-Default.desktop', 'chrome-hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki-Default.desktop', 'chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Default.desktop', ]
```

Would appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this, I'm sure the solution would benefit quite a few people.

Comment: A little more info.
I tried pasting the echoed output into dconf editor and found the last , and space were the problem so just need to edit the printf to not end with , space.


An entirely new solution that would also add any future installed chrome apps to said folder would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem with the script the ,[space] after the final .desktop was causing the error, so removed it using sed.

This now works:

```
applist=$(printf "'%s', " $(cd /home/rob/.local/share/applications; ls chrome*.desktop))
applist="[$(sed -e 's/[,[:space:]]*$//' <<<${applist})]"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/ChromeApps/ name 'Chrome Apps'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/ChromeApps/ apps "${applist}"
```

I still wish there was a solution that could do this dynamically e.g. if I set up a media subgroup / folder then installed VLC as an example it  would automatically add it to the group. Same for chrome apps to a set group. Adding apps manually in whichever form be it dconf, gsettings or a gui like Meow is a bit cumbersome.

This type of script + cron is at least a start, I hope people make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

By now I am a little bit confused which kind of help is OK by the rules here, so I hope this time it may be OK to suggest a tool that is directly linked to the problem, instead of a solution through fighting script-fu.

Try "GNOME App Folders Manager" or "Meow". With this tools you can reorganize your folders and apps in a matter of minutes without scripting around.

But you have to decide which one of these you want to use before you start reorganizing your apps. Because "Meow" can't see the changes made by "Gnome App Folders Manager" and vice versa.

Comment: This isn't a solution. OP wants to delegate his Chrome Apps to a certain folder/subgroup.

Comment: ?? And the purpose of the suggested GUI Tools is what? But it is indeed not the s

Comment: solution he had in mind. I got it now, excuse me he wanted to automate the folder sorting of new apps via script for future apps and existing.  .... Note to myself, keep in mind that "Enter" is a bad Button while writing a comment :-).

Comment: I'm going to thank you for the answer, not quite what i was looking for but it's nice to know about meow and Gnome App Folders Manager. The people whose systems i maintain will appreciate the ability to organise their apps without relying on me.

Comment: I am not deep enough into script-fu but I think even future efforts will be for nothing :-(. I will be guessing into the blue now. Your script will need some kind of a trigger to sort the *.desktop files into the right categories. This trigger is the "Categories=XY;" part in the *.desktop file, right ? When you look at for example 10 *.desktop files that could probabaly be sorted under a multimedia tag, you will see that for some Apps the "Categories=XY" is missing, for others it is just "audio" or "audio & video" in for the rest of the files and so on.....